# Is Multi level Clone solution in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one help to multi level Clone solution for this [Can I have multiple levels of nested cloned forms using SheepIt JQuery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047937/can-i-have-multiple-levels-of-nested-cloned-forms-using-sheepit-jquery-plugin)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you want solve his problem or you have different problem then try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945061/jquery-error-cannot-call-method-indexof-of-undefined)?

Comment: Yes, but it is not working, can you please provide working example, I want the solution for this question : Can I have multiple levels of nested cloned forms using SheepIt JQuery plugin?, please go to this URL

Comment: Show me what you tried and what error you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [For reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765900/how-to-call-ajax-function-after-form-elements-are-cloned-using-jquery)

```
afterAdd:function (data) {
    initializeAutotab($('input.autotab', data));
    initializeDatePicker(data);
}
```

if you are using nested forms, you must specify the same afterAdd to the nested options.

Regardless, this is an alternative to using live/on.

also note that you want to use afterAdd instead of afterClone because afterClone seems to be before the content is actually added to the DOM.

Comment: Okay, My issue is not this, please go to this URL : http://jsfiddle.net/njB5t/ you will see "add test", when you click it works, when you click on address under "add test", it is not working for second level clone for test